# Can you grab a webpage contents and the cookies?

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine

I have a google apps domain that i'd like to create a custom login page for but am having problems.

Google provides documentation for SSO/OpenID/userApi that will do this. The implementation on these docs that I can understand states once a user hits your site they will be sent to the regular gmail login and then sent back to your site once logged in. I'm trying to have them login in a custom page and not be sent over to googles default gmail login. There is other documentation that seems to require SSO and a lot of integration that I am too incompetent to understand which would let you do that, but as I said it's way over my head.

Then I thought I could just copy the form element and create custom css seeing as the action value on the form would authenticate via google. This worked sporadically until I figured out that when you go to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth (the default gmail login) it creates a value (name="GALX" value=Randomletters) in the html form that must match a cookies name and value to be able to submit and authenticate to google.

From here I thought no problem I'll create a hidden iframe to the google login so the cookie populates (it does get the cookie) and then read and insert the value in the html form. That is until I discovered you cannot alter or read another domains cookies for security reasons which makes perfect sense.

Then I thought I could just use php's file_get_contents on the gmail login url to get cookie and the right html and just insert the html into my custom page. I received the html but no cookie this time.

Is there anyway to send a request that would return the html/cookie pair with something like php's file_get_contents('url') or curl? This way I could traverse the file_get_contents object and insert the html into the page via the DOM. Or am I barking up a tree that will never work because security reasons specifically prevent this?

If the above isn't possible could someone explain how I could login my users via a custom login screen?
the google docs for such a project are:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/#Python_Signing_in_and_out
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for...
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Comment: Im looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php with this how would the cookie be set?